# [Stock-ROM][ROOT] Sense TW102 Android 11 Firmware

Tags: rooting, device-firmware, android-11, stock-rom

I have a Sense TW102 and I'm trying to root my device with hours of research and trial and error trying to find a way to find stock firmware to trying to pull it off my device with no avail. Any leads or advice id greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I feel this is off topic.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Please per-use our canonical Q&A about finding stock firmware. If you can't find it, then I'm afraid there's none on the internet.